# Show a view on ngclick

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui

I am really a newbie in angular, and now I am stuck with one problem. I have a grid which has multiple columns. One of the column contains the indicators which are nothing but `<a>` tags.
What I want to do is when the user clicks on the link I want to show/hide a view.
This view will have its own controller and functions. I want to pass on the FileId to this view and fetch records related to that File and then load the div relative to the link.

So If I have following two controllers.

```js
angular.module('testapp', [])
  .controller('loader-main', function($scope) {
    $scope.filesLoaded = [{
      "FileId": 1,
      "FileName": "File1.xls",
      "RejectedCount": "10",
    }, {
      "FileId": 2,
      "FileName": "File2.xls",
      "RejectedCount": "5",
    }];

    $scope.toggle = function(fileId) { //This function should toggle the rc div
      //Not sure how to load the RC div relative to the Link and pass on the FileId
      $scope.whenREjectedCOuntClicked = true;
    };

  })
  .controller('rejectedContents', function($scope) {
    $scope.whenRejectedCountClicked = false;

    //Records are actually fetched from a web service which is commented out. 
    //I need to pass the file Id that was selected in the loader-main scope..
    $scope.records = [{
      "Id": 1,
      "Name": "ABC"
    }, {
      "Id": 2,
      "Name": "XYZ"
    }]

    //WebSerivcce.getRecords(FileId);
  });




//And here is my html
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="testapp">

<body>
  <div ng-controller="loader-main">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>File Name
        </th>
        <th>Rejected Count
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="file in filesLoaded">
        <td>{{file.FileName}}</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;"><a href="javascropt:void(0)" ng-click="toggle(file.FileId)">{{file.RejectedCount}}</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div name="rc" ng-controller="rejectedContents" ng-show="whenRejectedCountClicked">
    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="r in records">
        <td>
          {{r.Id}}
        </td>
        <td>
          {{r.Name}}
        </td>
        <tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is mock snapshot of what I want to achieve. So if the user clicks on link 5 he would see a div and grid inside that div just below the link.

[image: showhidediv]

Let me know if anyone needs anymore information...

Thank You.. N

Comment: Can you tell me what exactly you want to know? What is the question?

Comment: Just imagine two divs Parent-> child. I want to show the child div as a popup(not a modal popup but similar to  tooltip) when any link is clicked in the parent div.

Comment: Just to be clear, do you want to know how to do this with angular or is this a styling question?

Comment: I want to do it with angular and bootstrap...